# Error al cargar imagen con Glide

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

estoy intentando cargar una imagen con Glide pero muestra el siguiente error, alguien tiene una idea de que podía estar pasando

```
class fragment_inbox: Fragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        Glide.with(this).load("http://goo.gl/gEgYUd").into(imagenone)
        }
}

W/Glide: Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule. You should include an annotationProcessor compile dependency on com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler in your application and a @GlideModule annotated AppGlideModule implementation or LibraryGlideModules will be silently ignored
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.app.Test, PID: 20089
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument must not be null
        at com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:29)
        at com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:23)
        at com.bumptech.glide.RequestBuilder.into(RequestBuilder.java:669)
        at com.app.Test.fragment_inbox.onCreate(fragment_inbox.kt:23)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2867)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:444)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1287)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2358)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2103)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2028)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1924)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:489)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8107)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

Al parecer en la primera linea del error dice que faltan las librerías, eso es lo que entiendo, pero estan puestas correctamente, en el lugar correcto.

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

El error no indica que faltan libraries, te sugiero revisar la documentación donde indica:

> La API generada solo está disponible para aplicaciones por ahora.
> Limitar la API generada a las aplicaciones nos permite tener una única
> implementación de la API, en lugar de N implementaciones, una por
> biblioteca y aplicación. Como resultado, es mucho más sencillo
> administrar las importaciones y garantizar que todas las rutas de
> llamadas dentro de una aplicación en particular tengan aplicadas las
> opciones correctas. Esta restricción puede levantarse
> (experimentalmente o de otro modo) en una versión futura.
>
> Por ahora, la API solo se genera cuando se encuentra un `AppGlideModule`
> debidamente anotado. Solo puede haber un `AppGlideModule` por
> aplicación. Como resultado, no es posible generar la API para una
> biblioteca sin impedir que cualquier aplicación que use la biblioteca
> use la API generada.

Te sugiero revisar:

https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/generatedapi.html

En el caso de Kotlin realiza lo siguiente, crea una clase que extienda de `AppGlideModule`  :

```
@GlideModule
public class GlideApp extends AppGlideModule {

}
```

y cambia `Glide` por `GlideApp`:

```
//Glide.with(this).load("http://goo.gl/gEgYUd").into(imagenone)
 Glide.with(this).load("http://goo.gl/gEgYUd").into(imagenone)
```

Agrega una dependencia `kapt` en lugar de una dependencia `annotationProcessor` en el procesador de anotaciones de Glide:

```
dependencies {
  kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
}
```

Tenga en cuenta que también debe incluir el complemento `kotlin-kapt` en su archivo `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

dentro de tu `build.gradle` asegura no usar `annotationProcessor` , usa `kapt`::

```
dependencies {
  ...
  ...
  kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
}
```